# Where is the Assisted class in the Guice jar?

Tags: java, maven, guice

I've download Guice 2.0 and 3.0 via Maven, and can't find the entire com.google.inject.assistedinject package in the jar. All the other components of Guice seem to be there, but [Assisted](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/latest-javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/Assisted.html) and its brethren are simply not there.

Any idea where they went?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Assisted is bundled with the rest of the [AssistedInjection](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject) extension as a separate artifact in the [com.google.inject.extensions](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject.extensions) group, along with Multibindings, Persistence and Servlet.

[4.0 is com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assistedinject:4.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject.extensions/guice-assistedinject/4.0)

[3.0 is com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assistedinject:3.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject.extensions/guice-assistedinject/3.0)

[2.0 is com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assisted-inject:2.0](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject.extensions/guice-assisted-inject/2.0)